# password working only in text mode but not in XWindows mode

Tags: password

I was trying to install Nividia GTX 950 M driver. For that i need to do Ctrl+Alt+F1 and then stop XWindows(sudo service lightdm stop). It got stopped and then i started running the installation of Nvidia driver.Once the driver installation went fine - it asked me to restart the laptop. After laptop at the unity login screen my password is not working. I checked everything - caps lock etc....but it's just not working....at the same time if i do Ctrl+Alt+F1 - the same password is working. 
When checking my installation of Nvidia graphics card using the command

```
less /var/log/Xorg.0.log | grep 'vendor'
```

i can find that it has installed Nvidia graphics driver properly and uninstalled default "Nouveau" driver.

I am wondering...what's going wrong...If i do  Ctrl+Alt+F7 - my password is not working.....what could go wrong?

I am using Ubuntu 14.0.4 Desktop - 64 bit version on intel Core I7 - quad core laptop with 16 GB RAM, 4 GB Graphics card(Nvidia GTX 950M)

Comment: You know... why did you even install the drivers from the .run package? The all-time recommended is running "Additional drivers" and installing everything from there. No headaches. Just purge the nvidia drivers (`sudo apt-get purge nvidia-*`) and reinstall them trough additional drivers.

Comment: By the way you'll have to install nouveau again. NEVER delete the default open source video drivers, since they are excellent fallback options. Just add them to the module blacklist, by creating a .conf file in /etc/modprobe.d with a `blacklist nouveau` line inside.

Comment: nouveau was not working fine with my dedicated nvidia graphics card. Ubuntu was freezing every 15 minutes. Right now the problem is resolved by installing the nvidia driver.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it was a very fresh install and I had enough troubles with Ubuntu Desktop 14.0.4 LTS - I decided to uninstall it and then install Ubuntu Desktop 15.10. No login loop issue, no wifi driver related issue and grub2 is also working fine. Only one issue is remaining now that is nvidia graphics card driver which is making ubuntu freeze. That is the only one to deal with now. Thanks everybody for providing tips for various questions and issues in askubuntu.com. It's really helpful.
able to fix the final issue also(though not fully) by loading the driver from ppa rather than nvidia site.
[askubuntu thread only](https://askubuntu.com/questions/721633/nvidia-graphics-card-driver-installed-led-to-login-loop)

Final update.
login loop and no vertical sidebar and title in unity desktop issue is also resolved now. Installed nvidia driver from ppa and then performed the following steps:

```
dconf reset -f /org/compiz/
```

then

```
setsid unity
```

Everything working fine now.

Comment: You don't need a ppa to install the driver; you can install the driver through apt-get. In fact, the ppa version is most likely causing the issue. You just need to enable the "restricted" repository to make it available.