# Nvidia graphics card driver installed led to login loop

Tags: nvidia

I am using Ubuntu 15.10 Desktop - 64 bit version on intel Core I7 - quad core laptop with 16 GB RAM, 4 GB Graphics card(Nvidia GTX 950M). After successful install - Ubuntu was freezing due to inbuilt and default graphics driver from Ubuntu is not good enough. I went ahead and installed "Nividia GTX 950 M driver" from 
http://www.nvidia.com/Download/driverResults.aspx/84043/en-us

and followed this link
[How do I install the Nvidia driver for a GeForce GT 630](https://askubuntu.com/questions/451221/ubuntu-14-04-install-nvidia-driver)

Successful install of Nvidia graphics card but I end up with login loop at the time of login(unity and lightdm).

Here are some of my files from /var/log/
syslog

```
Jan 15 17:34:42 ashu-HP-ENVY-Notebook org.ayatana.bamf[1587]: Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":0".
Jan 15 17:34:43 ashu-HP-ENVY-Notebook gnome-session[1733]: Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":0".
Jan 15 17:34:43 ashu-HP-ENVY-Notebook gnome-session[1733]: message repeated 3 times: [ Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":0".]
Jan 15 17:34:43 ashu-HP-ENVY-Notebook gnome-session[1733]: gnome-session-is-accelerated: No hardware 3D support.
Jan 15 17:34:43 ashu-HP-ENVY-Notebook gnome-session[1733]: Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":0".
```

auth.log

```
Jan 15 17:31:32 ashu-HP-ENVY-Notebook systemd-logind[677]: Power key pressed.
Jan 15 17:31:32 ashu-HP-ENVY-Notebook systemd-logind[677]: Powering Off...
Jan 15 17:31:32 ashu-HP-ENVY-Notebook systemd-logind[677]: System is powering down.
Jan 15 17:31:32 ashu-HP-ENVY-Notebook su[2022]: pam_unix(su:session): session closed for user root
Jan 15 17:31:32 ashu-HP-ENVY-Notebook sudo: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
Jan 15 17:34:33 ashu-HP-ENVY-Notebook systemd-logind[642]: New seat seat0.
Jan 15 17:34:33 ashu-HP-ENVY-Notebook systemd-logind[642]: Watching system buttons on /dev/input/event2 (Power Button)
Jan 15 17:34:33 ashu-HP-ENVY-Notebook systemd-logind[642]: Watching system buttons on /dev/input/event5 (Video Bus)
Jan 15 17:34:33 ashu-HP-ENVY-Notebook systemd-logind[642]: Watching system buttons on /dev/input/event4 (Video Bus)
Jan 15 17:34:33 ashu-HP-ENVY-Notebook systemd-logind[642]: Watching system buttons on /dev/input/event1 (Power Button)
Jan 15 17:34:33 ashu-HP-ENVY-Notebook systemd-logind[642]: Watching system buttons on /dev/input/event0 (Lid Switch)
Jan 15 17:34:34 ashu-HP-ENVY-Notebook lightdm: PAM unable to dlopen(pam_kwallet.so): /lib/security/pam_kwallet.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Jan 15 17:34:34 ashu-HP-ENVY-Notebook lightdm: PAM adding faulty module: pam_kwallet.so
Jan 15 17:34:34 ashu-HP-ENVY-Notebook lightdm: PAM unable to dlopen(pam_kwallet5.so): /lib/security/pam_kwallet5.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Jan 15 17:34:34 ashu-HP-ENVY-Notebook lightdm: PAM adding faulty module: pam_kwallet5.so
Jan 15 17:34:34 ashu-HP-ENVY-Notebook lightdm: pam_unix(lightdm-greeter:session): session opened for user lightdm by (uid=0)
Jan 15 17:34:34 ashu-HP-ENVY-Notebook systemd-logind[642]: New session c1 of user lightdm.
Jan 15 17:34:34 ashu-HP-ENVY-Notebook systemd: pam_unix(systemd-user:session): session opened for user lightdm by (uid=0)
Jan 15 17:34:34 ashu-HP-ENVY-Notebook lightdm: PAM unable to dlopen(pam_kwallet.so): /lib/security/pam_kwallet.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Jan 15 17:34:34 ashu-HP-ENVY-Notebook lightdm: PAM adding faulty module: pam_kwallet.so
Jan 15 17:34:34 ashu-HP-ENVY-Notebook lightdm: PAM unable to dlopen(pam_kwallet5.so): /lib/security/pam_kwallet5.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Jan 15 17:34:34 ashu-HP-ENVY-Notebook lightdm: PAM adding faulty module: pam_kwallet5.so
Jan 15 17:34:34 ashu-HP-ENVY-Notebook lightdm: pam_succeed_if(lightdm:auth): requirement "user ingroup nopasswdlogin" not met by user "ashu"
Jan 15 17:34:37 ashu-HP-ENVY-Notebook dbus[667]: [system] Rejected send message, 10 matched rules; type="method_return", sender=":1.63" (uid=0 pid=1198 comm="/usr/sbin/dnsmasq --no-resolv --keep-in-foreground") interface="(unset)" member="(unset)" error name="(unset)" requested_reply="0" destination=":1.14" (uid=0 pid=687 comm="/usr/sbin/NetworkManager --no-daemon ")
Jan 15 17:34:42 ashu-HP-ENVY-Notebook lightdm: pam_unix(lightdm-greeter:session): session closed for user lightdm
Jan 15 17:34:42 ashu-HP-ENVY-Notebook lightdm: pam_unix(lightdm:session): session opened for user ashu by (uid=0)
Jan 15 17:34:42 ashu-HP-ENVY-Notebook systemd-logind[642]: New session c2 of user ashu.
Jan 15 17:34:42 ashu-HP-ENVY-Notebook systemd: pam_unix(systemd-user:session): session opened for user ashu by (uid=0)
Jan 15 17:34:43 ashu-HP-ENVY-Notebook lightdm: pam_unix(lightdm:session): session closed for user ashu
Jan 15 17:34:43 ashu-HP-ENVY-Notebook systemd-logind[642]: Removed session c2.
Jan 15 17:34:43 ashu-HP-ENVY-Notebook systemd: pam_unix(systemd-user:session): session closed for user ashu
Jan 15 17:34:44 ashu-HP-ENVY-Notebook lightdm: PAM unable to dlopen(pam_kwallet.so): /lib/security/pam_kwallet.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Jan 15 17:34:44 ashu-HP-ENVY-Notebook lightdm: PAM adding faulty module: pam_kwallet.so
Jan 15 17:34:44 ashu-HP-ENVY-Notebook lightdm: PAM unable to dlopen(pam_kwallet5.so): /lib/security/pam_kwallet5.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Jan 15 17:34:44 ashu-HP-ENVY-Notebook lightdm: PAM adding faulty module: pam_kwallet5.so
Jan 15 17:34:44 ashu-HP-ENVY-Notebook lightdm: pam_unix(lightdm-greeter:session): session opened for user lightdm by (uid=0)
Jan 15 17:34:44 ashu-HP-ENVY-Notebook systemd-logind[642]: New session c3 of user lightdm.
Jan 15 17:34:44 ashu-HP-ENVY-Notebook lightdm: PAM unable to dlopen(pam_kwallet.so): /lib/security/pam_kwallet.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Jan 15 17:34:44 ashu-HP-ENVY-Notebook lightdm: PAM adding faulty module: pam_kwallet.so
Jan 15 17:34:44 ashu-HP-ENVY-Notebook lightdm: PAM unable to dlopen(pam_kwallet5.so): /lib/security/pam_kwallet5.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Jan 15 17:34:44 ashu-HP-ENVY-Notebook lightdm: PAM adding faulty module: pam_kwallet5.so
Jan 15 17:34:44 ashu-HP-ENVY-Notebook lightdm: pam_succeed_if(lightdm:auth): requirement "user ingroup nopasswdlogin" not met by user "ashu"
Jan 15 17:34:54 ashu-HP-ENVY-Notebook login[941]: pam_unix(login:session): session opened for user ashu by LOGIN(uid=0)
Jan 15 17:34:54 ashu-HP-ENVY-Notebook systemd-logind[642]: New session c4 of user ashu.
Jan 15 17:34:54 ashu-HP-ENVY-Notebook systemd: pam_unix(systemd-user:session): session opened for user ashu by (uid=0)
Jan 15 17:35:00 ashu-HP-ENVY-Notebook sudo:     ashu : TTY=tty1 ; PWD=/home/ashu ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/bin/su
Jan 15 17:35:00 ashu-HP-ENVY-Notebook sudo: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by ashu(uid=0)
Jan 15 17:35:00 ashu-HP-ENVY-Notebook su[2001]: Successful su for root by root
Jan 15 17:35:00 ashu-HP-ENVY-Notebook su[2001]: + /dev/tty1 root:root
Jan 15 17:35:00 ashu-HP-ENVY-Notebook su[2001]: pam_unix(su:session): session opened for user root by ashu(uid=0)
Jan 15 17:35:00 ashu-HP-ENVY-Notebook su[2001]: pam_systemd(su:session): Cannot create session: Already running in a session
```

Nvidia installer logs seems to be okay too.
What could be the problem? The password is working fine when i use Ctrl+Alt+F1 and then login to the terminal.

Here is the last few lines of nvidia installer logs

```
    -> Searching for conflicting files:
-> done.
-> Installing 'NVIDIA Accelerated Graphics Driver for Linux-x86_64' (349.16):
   executing: '/sbin/ldconfig'...
   executing: '/sbin/depmod -aq '...
-> done.
-> Driver file installation is complete.
-> Running post-install sanity check:
-> done.
-> Post-install sanity check passed.
-> Running runtime sanity check:
-> done.
-> Runtime sanity check passed.
-> Installation of the kernel module for the NVIDIA Accelerated Graphics Driver for Linux-x86_64 (version 349.16) is now complete.
```

syslog important logs

```
Jan 15 17:34:42 ashu-HP-ENVY-Notebook systemd[1485]: Startup finished in 10ms.
Jan 15 17:34:42 ashu-HP-ENVY-Notebook systemd[1]: Started User Manager for UID 1000.
Jan 15 17:34:42 ashu-HP-ENVY-Notebook org.a11y.Bus[1587]: Activating service name='org.a11y.atspi.Registry'
Jan 15 17:34:42 ashu-HP-ENVY-Notebook org.a11y.Bus[1587]: Successfully activated service 'org.a11y.atspi.Registry'
Jan 15 17:34:42 ashu-HP-ENVY-Notebook org.a11y.atspi.Registry[1657]: SpiRegistry daemon is running with well-known name - org.a11y.atspi.Registry
Jan 15 17:34:42 ashu-HP-ENVY-Notebook org.ayatana.bamf[1587]: Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":0".
Jan 15 17:34:43 ashu-HP-ENVY-Notebook gnome-session[1733]: Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":0".
Jan 15 17:34:43 ashu-HP-ENVY-Notebook gnome-session[1733]: message repeated 3 times: [ Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":0".]
Jan 15 17:34:43 ashu-HP-ENVY-Notebook gnome-session[1733]: gnome-session-is-accelerated: No hardware 3D support.
Jan 15 17:34:43 ashu-HP-ENVY-Notebook gnome-session[1733]: Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":0".
Jan 15 17:34:43 ashu-HP-ENVY-Notebook gnome-session[1733]: gnome-session-check-accelerated: Helper exited with code 256
Jan 15 17:34:43 ashu-HP-ENVY-Notebook gnome-session[1733]: gnome-session[1733]: CRITICAL: We failed, but the fail whale is dead. Sorry....
Jan 15 17:34:43 ashu-HP-ENVY-Notebook gnome-session[1733]: CRITICAL: We failed, but the fail whale is dead. Sorry....
Jan 15 17:34:43 ashu-HP-ENVY-Notebook lightdm[900]: ** (lightdm:900): CRITICAL **: session_get_login1_session_id: assertion 'session != NULL' failed
Jan 15 17:34:43 ashu-HP-ENVY-Notebook systemd[1]: Stopping User Manager for UID 1000...
Jan 15 17:34:43 ashu-HP-ENVY-Notebook systemd[1485]: Reached target Shutdown.
Jan 15 17:34:43 ashu-HP-ENVY-Notebook systemd[1485]: Starting Exit the Session...
Jan 15 17:34:43 ashu-HP-ENVY-Notebook systemd[1485]: Stopped target Default.
Jan 15 17:34:43 ashu-HP-ENVY-Notebook systemd[1485]: Stopped target Basic System.
Jan 15 17:34:43 ashu-HP-ENVY-Notebook systemd[1485]: Stopped target Paths.
Jan 15 17:34:43 ashu-HP-ENVY-Notebook systemd[1485]: Stopped target Sockets.
Jan 15 17:34:43 ashu-HP-ENVY-Notebook systemd[1485]: Stopped target Timers.
Jan 15 17:34:43 ashu-HP-ENVY-Notebook systemd[1485]: Received SIGRTMIN+24 from PID 1780 (kill).
```

Full auth.log
http://pastebin.com/kMtMQHmC

Full Xorg.0.log
http://pastebin.com/94kHcF1b

**I have checked that it's nvidia driver only which is loaded and nouveau is disabled(or not loaded). The nvidia driver i got it from nvidia website only.**

Comment: already tried chown and chmod for .XAuthority and home directory and that didn't fix the problem of login loop for Unity desktop at the time of startup.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Generally you should use the drivers from the official Ubuntu repositories.

Because you are having problems, using the latest drivers might be better.  Install the latest official stable NVIDIA drivers for the GEFORCE GTX 950M.

First uninstall the currently installed NVIDIA drivers.  Boot the computer, when the GRUB menu appears ...

Highlight the Ubuntu menu entry and  press the <kbd>E</kbd> key.  Add `nouveau.modeset=0` to the end of the linux line.  Press <kbd>F10</kbd> to boot the Ubuntu operating system.

When the login screen appears press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>.  Enter your user name and the password, then execute :

```
sudo apt-get purge nvidia*  
sudo reboot
```

Now install the latest official stable NVIDIA drivers.  Boot the computer, when the GRUB menu appears ...

Highlight the Ubuntu menu entry and  press the <kbd>E</kbd> key.  Add `nouveau.modeset=0` to the end of the linux line.  Press <kbd>F10</kbd> to boot the Ubuntu operating system.

When the login screen appears press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>.
Enter your user name and the password, then execute :

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nvidia-358 nvidia-prime
sudo reboot
```

Note:

Maybe it is explicitly necessary to select the NVIDIA adapter in BIOS.  When you want to use drivers 352, adding the PPA is not necessary.  In this case the terminal commands you have to perform are these:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nvidia-352 nvidia-prime
sudo reboot
```

Comment: Thanks cl-netbox. What is nvidia-prime? Is this one "apt-get install nvidia-358 nvidia-prime" will install the compatible nvidia graphics driver for my Nvidia GEForce GTX 950M dedicated card?

Comment: @Ashu : Yes - this will install the NVIDIA drivers 358 and nvidia-prime, which will let you switch between intel and NVIDIA graphics. :)

Comment: Can you share some more details or links? I have dedicated nvidia graphics card and after installing it(properly after following all the instructions) - i have login loop. Why the solution provided by you will work? Please explain with more detail.

Comment: @Ashu : From my experience ... I solved many similar problems on Ask Ubuntu with this solution, nearly all of them successfully. The problem is, that every machine has completely different hardware components or BIOS settings ... maybe you have to enable NVIDIA graphics in BIOS ? Another thing is, that you tried to install the drivers in a different way before - there could have been something completely going wrong. :)

Comment: thanks for your answer. I have installed nvidia driver from nvidia site only and this is a fresh installation. Going thru the ppa documentation at here "https://launchpad.net/~graphics-drivers/+archive/ubuntu/ppa" it seems they are also advocating(or recommending) for "nvidia-352". I have ubuntu 14.0.4 Desktop(64 bit) running on my desktop and their i just used the nvidia graphics card driver from nvidia site and it's working all fine-no issues at all. That's why i am asking. Proprietary driver should always be better than opensource ones, right?

Comment: @Ashu : Both are proprietary NVIDIA drivers ... 352 are from the long-lived branch and 358 are from the short-lived branch. But now you confused me when you say, it's all working fine ? In case I misunderstood : please try it again ... but this time, please set the parameter nomodeset instead of nouveau.modeset=0 ! :)

Comment: @Ashu : When you installed the drivers from NVIDIA website manually, please uninstall them manually as well, before installing the drivers from repositories - also, this is the matching link to the Proprietary GPU drivers PPA -> https://launchpad.net/~graphics-drivers/+archive/ubuntu/ppa :)

Comment: @cl-net.I have multiple laptops and desktops.In one of the desktop which has Nvidia GeForce GT 610 graphics card.I just went to the nvidia website and download the driver binary from there and installed it.It worked like a charm.No freezing and no issues at all.What i am talking now is other laptop which has Nvidia GeForce GTX 950M graphics card. For this also i installed graphics card driver from here "http://www.nvidia.com/Download/driverResults.aspx/84043/en-us" as the nouveau was freezing.This is new installation & after that i just installed this driver.I end up with login loop issue.

Comment: @Ashu : Okay, now it is clear ... notebooks with NVIDIA Optimus support are a completely different thing. As it is a fresh installation and you didn't have configured much yet, the easiest way to solve the problem is to reinstall the system and afterwards first installing the graphics drivers following the instructions. :)

Comment: It's a reinstall only.I had installed ubuntu desktop 14.0.4 in the past on this laptop and the same issue.With ubuntu desktop14.0.4 - i had another issue - my wifi was not working. Upgrading to 15.10 at least made my wifi work. Though i am having the same login loop issue at the time the unity desktop is presented at the startup. So i am sticking to ubuntu 15.10 and trying for this graphics card driver.thanks for all your help.

Comment: @cl-netbox...Oh sorry...is it not possible to have multiple correct answers...actually i just accepted my answer also a correct answer...and i think when somebody does that the previously accepted correct answer goes away...i have undone my action...sorry for that.

Comment: I just got the generic kernel 4.2.0 and after that the same issue. I upgraded to nvidia-361 also...but getting black screen. Any help?

Comment: @Ashu : I suggest that you completely uninstall and reinstall the NVIDIA drivers - follow exactly the instructions described in the answer - also make sure that you have dkms (sudo apt-get install dkms) installed. :)

Comment: I downloaded the graphic card driver from NVIDIA's official website and have successfully installed it. My experience was: say "no" to its xconfig prompt at the end of the installation, and do NOT run xconfig after the installation, otherwise you would enter infinite loop again.

Comment: Key for me was the `nouveau.modeset=0` setting.

Answer (score 2):

[image]Thanks cl-netbox to some extent I am able to resolve the issue.
This is what i have done

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nvidia-358
sudo reboot
```

Please make sure that if you went to the nividia website and installed the driver from there(N*.run) - you must un-install this by going to /usr/bin/nvidia-installer. There should be something like nvidia-install(link to uninstall). Run that one and follow all the instructions. You should install the nvidia drivers from the ppa repository after cleaning up(purging the previous nvidia install). There is a bug in ubuntu and any time there is any issue in terms of installing the nvidia driver - you will end up with login loop.

I am out of the login loop issue.  The only issue that i am facing now is that once i login into Unity desktop-i am not seeing sidebar...(resolution issue)-terminal etc....are not having the title bar etc....so it seems some more steps are needed to fix the entire set. But yes I am out of that irritating login loop issue now.

***Next update - I was missing the sidebar via which i can launch applications and that got fixed via:***
Was able to get rid of the unity desktop issue also finally. I was able to do Right click and open the terminal. Tried many solutions as mentioned in this thread as well as others. Finally this worked for me.

```
dconf reset -f /org/compiz/
```

then

```
setsid unity
```

Everything seems to be working fine now. Thanks everybody

Answer (score -1):

A simple solution for me is, make sure your cable is plugged into the graphic card instead of the motherboard. IF you plug it into the motherboard, I am guessing ubuntu get confused somewehere.

I have been dealing this problem for so long and finally this works for me. Thanks god.

I just plug it into the GPU and reboot. problem solved.

I have nvr thought about using the GPU for display because I am writing CUDA program and I dun really need the graphics from the graphic card.

I also have to edit grub 
 - remove gtfxmode line on line3/4 
 - add nomodeset noquiet and nosplash