# nvidia-settings crashing after selecting a display

Tags: nvidia, nvidia-settings

After a fresh first install of ubuntu 14.04 LTS on my computer I had some issues with nvidia, especially with the nvidia-settings. When I try to change the resolution and press 'Apply' it just closes e outputs an error on my terminal:

```
The program 'nvidia-settings' received an X Window System error.
This probably reflects a bug in the program.
The error was 'BadValue (integer parameter out of range for operation)'.
 (Details: serial 785 error_code 2 request_code 157 minor_code 25)
  (Note to programmers: normally, X errors are reported asynchronously;
   that is, you will receive the error a while after causing it.
   To debug your program, run it with the --sync command line
   option to change this behavior. You can then get a meaningful
   backtrace from your debugger if you break on the gdk_x_error() function.)
```

I tried to open with the search option and with sudo on terminal

Output of dpkg -l | grep nvidia:

```
ii  nvidia-304                                                  304.131-0ubuntu0.14.04.1                            i386         NVIDIA legacy binary driver - version 304.131
ii  nvidia-current                                              304.131-0ubuntu0.14.04.1                            i386         Transitional package for nvidia-current
rc  nvidia-libopencl1-304                                       304.131-0ubuntu0.14.04.1                            i386         NVIDIA OpenCL Driver and ICD Loader library
ii  nvidia-opencl-icd-304                                       304.131-0ubuntu0.14.04.1                            i386         NVIDIA OpenCL ICD
ii  nvidia-settings                                             331.20-0ubuntu8                                     i386         Tool for configuring the NVIDIA graphics driver
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will suggest try this:

```
sudo apt-get purge nvidia*  
sudo reboot 

sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nvidia-358
sudo reboot
```

For more details, refer to my [thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/722444/nvidia-problem-freeze-computer-14-04-x64/722450#722450)

This is how it looks like in my system

```
root@ashu-700-430qe:/var/opt# dpkg -l | grep nvidia
ii  nvidia-358                                            358.16-0ubuntu0~gpu14.04.2                          amd64        NVIDIA binary driver - version 358.16
ii  nvidia-opencl-icd-358                                 358.16-0ubuntu0~gpu14.04.2                          amd64        NVIDIA OpenCL ICD
ii  nvidia-prime                                          0.6.2                                               amd64        Tools to enable NVIDIA's Prime
ii  nvidia-settings                                       361.28-0ubuntu0~gpu14.04.1                          amd64        Tool for configuring the NVIDIA graphics driver
root@ashu-700-430qe:/var/opt#
```