# Ubuntu 14.04 Menu and Side bars NOT displaying after Python3 uninstalled

Tags: 14.04, python, python3

I've uninstalled Python3 and now my Side and Menu Bars are not displaying. I'm running Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. 
I can still see my other icons on the desktop.
I've tried to launch Terminal( Alt+Cntrl+T) - not working.
I've already tried installing Ununtu-Desktop and ran an Update too. Didn't help me at all.
Can any one help?

Thanks guys!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
dconf reset -f /org/compiz/
```

then

```
setsid unity
```

It worked for me. Refer this [link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/721633/nvidia-graphics-card-driver-installed-led-to-login-loop/721814#721814) for more details.

Comment: Thanks for helping, but I think my case is more revere, because your commands didn't fix my problem, still not seeing all menus and bars.. Maybe it would help if I add that I'd uninstallef Python3 after installing it in an attempt to get my system ready to get OneDrive_D running. I think more files that were necessary had been automatically removed during the Python3 uninstall.

Answer (score 0):

I've faced the same problem and solved it by reinstalling desktop.

If <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd> does not open the terminal, press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd> and login to your user account.

Firstly, reinstall Python3:

```
sudo apt-get install python3
```

Now uninstall Ubuntu desktop:

```
sudo apt-get remove ubuntu-desktop
```

Finally reinstall your desktop:

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
```