# My Ubuntu will not load after login or if does login it will crash eventually

Tags: nvidia

[image]

I have installed Ubuntu 14.04 and every time I try to log in the screen will freeze and won't let me do anything else. I have tried running Ubuntu from a USB as well but the same issue still persist. The screen freezes or the whole computer locks up and I have to do.a restart. I know it has to do with nvidia graphics card but I can't seem to find the correct command to make it work. This is my first post on Ubuntu, so I apologize I know this question has been answered before somewhere.

Here is the info on video driver:

[image]

Sorry for any duplicates of the same issue if it has been addressed before.
Thanks
Michael

Answer (score 0):

If you have installed nvidia drivers from their website, please remove it following the installer instructions. You can still login to Ubuntu using Ctrl+Alt+F1 for that.

Now follow these steps(login to terminal using Ctrl+Alt+F1)
First purge any nvidia drivers

```
sudo apt-get purge nvidia*  
sudo reboot
```

Then install it from the ppa

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nvidia-358
sudo reboot
```

For more details, refer to this [thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/721633/nvidia-graphics-card-driver-installed-led-to-login-loop)

If sidebar is missing then try this
Press Ctrl+Alt+F1 to got to tty and log in, now run this

```
dconf reset -f /org/compiz/
```

then

```
setsid unity
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply I did the steps above but still no go. I am able to log in but then just get a blank desktop no launcher. The desktop screen is orange and then after a few minutes the screen starts to have lines in the screen.Thanks

Comment: @kb0vwg. Try the above solution. If this fixes your issue - accept this as correct answer by tick mark.

Comment: Tried the dconf reset -f /org/compiz/ But what I get in return is. error: cannot autolaunch D-Bus without x11 $DISPLAY  Usage: dconf reset [-f] path and then it gives a few arguments  PATH or KEY or DIR and then returns back to the prompt for a command

Comment: I am starting to wonder if this pc just does not like ubuntu period. I have ubuntu on 2 of my home computers with zero issues. they are both HP and they have nvidia video cards and no issues. I dont have much hair left to pull out lol.