# Unable to run Ubuntu on a MSI laptop without disabling ACPI

Tags: boot, bios, acpi, msi

I own a MSI GP62 6QE-260XFR, which is a laptop featuring an i5-6300HQ CPU and a GTX 950M graphics card, sold without OS.

I've installed Windows 10 on a partition. It works just fine. My problem is that I'm unable to run a Linux OS without the `acpi=off` boot option.

The boot error is the following:

```
ACPI : EC: Fail in evaluating the _REG object of EC device. Broken bios is suspected.
```

I've managed to install and run Ubuntu on a partition thanks to [this guide](https://forum.ubuntu-fr.org/viewtopic.php?pid=21458874#p21458874) (in French) for recent MSI computers. It basically consisted in:

- Disabling CPU C-States in BIOS
- Running an Ubuntu Live USB with the following boot options: `nouveau.blacklist=1 acpi=off` before `quiet splash`
- Installing Ubuntu
- Running the installed OS with the same boot options
- Updating the system and installing NVIDIA drivers

By then I should have been able to run Ubuntu without `acpi=off`, but I get the same error message as before. I've installed the latest version of the kernel (4.4.1), hoping it would be more compatible with my PC but the problem is the same.

Thanks to the ACPI being disabled, I can't see battery levels, which makes Ubuntu a bit unusable. Does someone know what I should do?

Comment: What special options, please elaborate?

Comment: For more details, here is my /var/log/kern.log: http://paste.ubuntu.com/15078065/

Answer (score 0):

I have the same Nvidia GTX 950 M graphics card and I made it work following:

```
sudo apt-get purge nvidia*  
sudo reboot

sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nvidia-361 
sudo reboot
```

I didn't specified any such params and I had just blacklisted nouveau and nothing else. My laptop is working all fine. I upgraded to kernel 4.2.5 for wifi issues.

Please refer to this [thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/721633/nvidia-graphics-card-driver-installed-led-to-login-loop) for more info.

Comment: I don't think the boot error really comes from the graphics card, but my drivers come from the same ppa as yours, though their version is 361. Did you add the nouveau blacklist in your permanent grub settings? I've tried to remove `acpi=off` but since the error comes from ACPI, I get the same error message.

Comment: @Kyrio : You are right ... the newest drivers version available is 361 ... I think your problem has more something  to do with your intel skylake CPU, which is known for having some compatibility issues. :)

Comment: @netbox Yes, I've read about that. But the kernel error doesn't seem CPU-related, and the guy who wrote the guide I used has a working Ubuntu with the exact same CPU :/ Plus Linux kernel 4.4 is designed for Skylake compatibility.

Comment: @Kyrio : Yes ... but you installed kernel 4.4.1 manually and not from the repositories, that's a difference ! :)

Comment: @cl-netbox It didn't work with the former kernel anyway :) I suppose you mean I should wait for 16.04 which comes bundled with kernel 4.4 ?

Comment: @Kyrio : Yes ... this is exactly what I meant ... what I recommend to you ... and ... what I do as well ! :)

Comment: @cl-netbox Well, that's what I was planning on doing at first, but I feel a bit... unfinished, having only W10 on this brand new laptop :/

Comment: Just asking, maybe BIOS should be updated?

Comment: @Avamander That is actually the first thing I tried, since BIOS was mentioned in the error message... That didn't change a thing :)

Comment: @Kyrio Could you please post /var/log/kern.log?

Comment: @Avamander Here it is: http://paste.ubuntu.com/15078065/

Comment: It indeed seems to be the graphics card. Try uninstalling everything Nvidia related and reinstall the proper graphics driver. `sudo apt-get purge nvidia* && sudo apt-get autoremove` and then get this 64bit `https://www.nvidia.com/download/driverResults.aspx/98373/en-us` driver and install it. You might also need to blacklist noveau from being loaded into memory.

Comment: @Avamander-installing from nvidia website is wrong advice. One should use the ppa - the one provided in my answer.

Comment: @Ashu Why is it wrong?

Comment: @Avamander. It didn't worked in my case - on two different machines. So that's why ppa approach is better

Comment: @Ashu Let him try your option first, if it doesn't work, let him try mine.

Comment: @Kyrio What's the status of your issue?

Comment: @Kyrio status pls