# Nvidia 361.28 and Intel graphic instaler 1.4.0 return login loop

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, xorg, login

When I install the latest nvdia driver 361.28 from **ppa:graphics-drivers**
I got a login loop. Currently I've installed the intelgraphics driver for linux with [Graphics Installer 1.4.0](https://01.org/linuxgraphics/downloads) that is published by intel.

When I delete all nvidia drivers by

```
sudo apt-get purge nvidia*
```

I am able to login normaly again. In this case the driver installation dialogue shows that the xorg nouveau driver is active.
Some people observed that the Xauthority file got the wrong owner when it comes to login errors. Moving the file by

```
mv .Xauthority .Xauthority.bak
```

Does not fix the problem.
How can I use the latest nvidia-drivers without getting stuck in login-loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am referring to this answer from my other answers.
I had a login loop issue as mentioned [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/721633/nvidia-graphics-card-driver-installed-led-to-login-loop)

First uninstall the currently installed NVIDIA drivers.Boot the computer, when the GRUB menu appears ...

Highlight the Ubuntu menu entry and press the E key.Add `nouveau.modeset=0` to the end of the linux line. Press F10 to boot the Ubuntu operating system.

When the login screen appears press Ctrl+Alt+F1.Enter your user name and the password, then execute :

```
sudo apt-get purge nvidia*  
sudo reboot
```

Now install the latest official stable NVIDIA drivers.Boot the computer, when the GRUB menu appears ...

Highlight the Ubuntu menu entry and press the E key.Add `nouveau.modeset=0` to the end of the linux line. Press F10 to boot the Ubuntu operating system.

When the login screen appears press Ctrl+Alt+F1. Enter your user name and the password, then execute :

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nvidia-361 nvidia-prime
sudo reboot
```

Note : Maybe it is explicitly necessary to select the NVIDIA adapter in BIOS. When you want to use drivers 361, adding the PPA is not necessary. In this case the terminal commands you have to perform are these :

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nvidia-361
sudo reboot
```

In case you have installed the nvidia driver from their site then uninstall it as per that instructions.Uninstall that driver by running, as root, `sh ./NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-361.28.run` and follow the on screen instructions.

Note : The solution I have provide has been tested on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS and Ubuntu 15.10 for two GPUs.