# Ubuntu 14.04 Infinite log in after installing nvidia drivers

Tags: 14.04, drivers, nvidia, login, lightdm

I just installed ubuntu and I'm trying to get the drivers for GTX 960m.

I followed the instructions given here:
https://elementaryforums.com/index.php?threads/howto-install-latest-nvidia-driver-on-linux-without-getting-black-screen.7/

Afterwards I tried to log in and I'm stuck in a loop. I tried all of the fixes I could find and none of them worked. At this point I don't know what else to do. Here is a picture of my error file:

[.xsession-errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AQBhP.jpg)

I'm sorry if this isn't enough information to go on. I don't really know what information to give or how to get it. I'd be happy to update this post with any information that would help. Thank you.

Comment: Related: http://askubuntu.com/search?q=login+loop

Answer (score 1):

I am referring to this answer from my other answers. I had a login loop issue as mentioned [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/721633/nvidia-graphics-card-driver-installed-led-to-login-loop)

First uninstall the currently installed NVIDIA drivers.Boot the computer, when the GRUB menu appears ...

Highlight the Ubuntu menu entry and press the E key.Add `nouveau.modeset=0` to the end of the linux line. Press F10 to boot the Ubuntu operating system.

When the login screen appears press Ctrl+Alt+F1.Enter your user name and the password, then execute :

```
sudo apt-get purge nvidia*  
sudo reboot
```

Now install the latest official stable NVIDIA drivers.Boot the computer, when the GRUB menu appears ...

Highlight the Ubuntu menu entry and press the E key.Add `nouveau.modeset=0` to the end of the linux line. Press F10 to boot the Ubuntu operating system.

When the login screen appears press Ctrl+Alt+F1. Enter your user name and the password, then execute :

```
    sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
    sudo apt-get update
    sudo apt-get install nvidia-361
    sudo reboot
```

Note : Maybe it is explicitly necessary to select the NVIDIA adapter in BIOS.

In case you have installed the nvidia driver from their site then uninstall it as per that instructions.Uninstall that driver by running, as root, `sh ./NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-361.28.run` and follow the on screen instructions.

Note : The solution I have provide has been tested on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS and Ubuntu 15.10 for two GPUs

Comment: "When you want to use drivers 361, adding the PPA is not necessary ..." This is not true - please correct your answer ! :) I think that giving you this information is more helpful for you than downvotes for your answer. :)

Comment: @cl-netbox. Is it the case because i need to do that both the times?

Comment: When you don't add the Proprietary GPU Drivers PPA, you can not install NVIDIA drivers 361, because they are not available in the Ubuntu repositories ... I improved the answer for you ... I hope you appreciate it ... :)