# Installing Ubuntu with nouveau error

Tags: system-installation, nouveau

This screen pops up when while trying to install Ubuntu. I'm not trying to dual boot.

```
0.219073] Ignoring BGRT: invalid status 0 (expected 1)
4.609665] ACPI PCC probe failed. 
4.768952] nouveau E[     DRM] failed to initialise sync subsystem, -38
```

Answer (score 1):

I am referring to this answer from my other answers.

First uninstall the currently installed NVIDIA drivers.Boot the computer, when the GRUB menu appears ...

Highlight the Ubuntu menu entry and press the E key.Add `nouveau.modeset=0` to the end of the linux line. Press F10 to boot the Ubuntu operating system.

When the login screen appears press Ctrl+Alt+F1.Enter your user name and the password, then execute :

```
sudo apt-get purge nvidia*  
sudo reboot
```

Now install the latest official stable NVIDIA drivers.Boot the computer, when the GRUB menu appears ...

Highlight the Ubuntu menu entry and press the E key.Add `nouveau.modeset=0` to the end of the linux line. Press F10 to boot the Ubuntu operating system.

When the login screen appears press Ctrl+Alt+F1. Enter your user name and the password, then execute :

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nvidia-361 nvidia-prime
sudo reboot
```

Note : Maybe it is explicitly necessary to select the NVIDIA adapter in BIOS. When you want to use drivers 361, adding the PPA is not necessary. In this case the terminal commands you have to perform are these :

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nvidia-361
sudo reboot
```

In case you have installed the nvidia driver from their site then uninstall it as per that instructions.Uninstall that driver by running, as root, `sh ./NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-361.28.run` and follow the on screen instructions.

Note : The solution I have provide has been tested on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS and Ubuntu 15.10 for two GPUs.

You can avoid the steps which are not needed in your case. Moreover the same steps - pressing E to edit boot params and F10 to save boot params are applicable even at the time of install.

Comment: Why do you make the same mistake again ? Please read : http://askubuntu.com/questions/741699/ubuntu-14-04-infinite-log-in-after-installing-nvidia-drivers/741719#comment1103719_741719 and correct.

Comment: I followed the first step and did the nouveau.modeset=o. It got rid of that error. I am however getting the ACPI PCC probe failed error. I've read other posts and saw people experiencing the same error. The post has 4 different answers and it doensn't clarify anything.