# Can not login after Nvidia driver installation

Tags: nvidia-geforce

I have installed Ubuntu 15.10 on my Xeon machine without any 
problems, but after installing Nvidia drivers (for GTX 960), I lose
my login password from the GUI. The password, however, works with the
console.

Can anyone help ?

---

Since I have tried three versions of Ubuntu, I am wondering why the
problem is still persisting even on Ubuntu 16.04 which has the latest
driver 361. Should we use Ububtu software or use ppa from Nvidia ?

Comment: How you installed nvidia drivers? Are you into the login loop?

Comment: Hello, i used ubuntu software. And by the way, your suggestion did not work

Answer (score 0):

I am referring to this answer from my other answers. I had a login loop issue as mentioned [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/721633/nvidia-graphics-card-driver-installed-led-to-login-loop). It seems you are also encountering login loop issue due to nvidia drivers issue.

First uninstall the currently installed NVIDIA drivers.Boot the computer, when the GRUB menu appears ...

Highlight the Ubuntu menu entry and press the E key.Add `nouveau.modeset=0` to the end of the linux line. Press F10 to boot the Ubuntu operating system.

When the login screen appears press Ctrl+Alt+F1.Enter your user name and the password, then execute :

```
sudo apt-get purge nvidia*  
sudo reboot
```

Now install the latest official stable NVIDIA drivers.Boot the computer, when the GRUB menu appears ...

Highlight the Ubuntu menu entry and press the E key.Add `nouveau.modeset=0` to the end of the linux line. Press F10 to boot the Ubuntu operating system.

When the login screen appears press Ctrl+Alt+F1. Enter your user name and the password, then execute :

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nvidia-361
sudo reboot
```

Note : Maybe it is explicitly necessary to select the NVIDIA adapter in BIOS.

In case you have installed the nvidia driver from their site then uninstall it as per that instructions.Uninstall that driver by running, as root, `sh ./NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-361.28.run` and follow the on screen instructions.

Note : The solution I have provide has been tested on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS and Ubuntu 15.10 for two GPUs

Answer (score 0):

I tried all version of ubuntu 14, 15, and 16. Same problems. I do not understand the first few steps, as I do not get the grub menu. I get 
directly ubuntu login menu. How and where I should set the nouveau.modeset=0.
Thanks.

Comment: To reveal the grub menu you need to press "Left Shift" or Press ESC during boot after your vendor boot screen