# ubuntu 16.04: When I change the video card driver from `nouveau` to `nvidia`, the top menu bar can't be displsyed?

Tags: unity, drivers, nvidia, 16.04

When I change my video card server to the `Nvidia dirver`, then when I log out, when I log in again, it turned back. Later, I changed the driver to `Nouveau`. When I reboot, the screen is a blank screen, there is no `top menu bar`, as well as the application. Then, I purged the `nouveau` driver and install the `nvidia` agian and again, the problem is the same.
I also tried some answers of [Ubuntu 16.04 + Nvidia Driver = Blank screen](https://askubuntu.com/questions/760374/ubuntu-16-04-nvidia-driver-blank-screen), but it doesn't work, so how can I roll back to the original state when I didn't change the driver.
Here is my screen capture:
[application screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fnc0U.png)
[additional driver and application panel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xk1pp.png)

and the `alt-tab` key can't be used. But I can open the terminal through the mouse `right click menu`.

Answer (score 0):

Mostly, that's the problem of your DE (GNOME, Lxde etc.), not the driver. Probably, the window manager fails to start, so you need to either reinstall your WM or your DE. Also you may try to run WM by yourself. Hope that helps.

Comment: Maybe it will help, but I have reinstalled the system.