# Black screen after installing CUDA 8.0rc from NVIDIA and unable to enter tty

Tags: nvidia, 16.04, tty

I'm unable to enter tty to use sudo service lightdm start, as the normal boot will not even get me able to press ctrl+alt+f1 to f6. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had a very similar problem where I got a blank screen when booting from an Ubuntu 16.04 Live USB on a GTX 1080, and found my answer in another question: [Ubuntu 16.04 + Nvidia Driver = Blank screen](https://askubuntu.com/questions/760374/ubuntu-16-04-nvidia-driver-blank-screen)

*Super-short version:* Add `nomodeset` to the boot options and then reinstall the NVIDIA drivers.

Longer version:

Most likely, CUDA installed NVIDIA drivers that don't work with your GPU.  Assuming you get to the GRUB menu on boot, press `e` to edit the boot command for Ubuntu, then add `nomodeset` to the options (it usually has `quiet splash` by default, so make it `nomodeset quiet splash`, for example). This should fix the graphics, but if not try adding `nouveau.modeset=0` and `nvidia.modeset=0` to the options as well.

Once you get into a terminal, you can install the correct drivers:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
sudo apt-get update
```

And then `sudo apt-get install nvidia-367`, assuming you want the latest drivers (as of this writing), or `apt-cache search nvidia` to see what's available. Once the new drivers are installed, you should be able to reboot without the nomodeset option and everything should work.

**A note when installing CUDA:** If you're ever reinstalling CUDA, I recommend using the the runfile method and **answering NO when it prompts to install drivers**, as I very much suspect the drivers are what caused the problem.