# black screen + auto shut down after Cuda 8.0 installed on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, cuda

I installed CUDA 8.0. After reboot, I ran into the blank screen without going further. And after a while, the CPU ran into full blast, and the machine shut down automatically. I was using Nvidia Driver 378.13 on GTX 1060. I have tried the solution mentioned in the following post, but it didn't work for me.

[Black screen after installing CUDA 8.0rc from NVIDIA and unable to enter tty](https://askubuntu.com/questions/808816/black-screen-after-installing-cuda-8-0rc-from-nvidia-and-unable-to-enter-tty)

Can anyone please help me on this? Thank you.

Comment: maybe helpful (it help him) [link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/852954/noveau-driver-unstable-causes-computer-freeze)

Answer (score 0):

I ran into similar issue.

I fixed it by removing secure boot UEFI.

> If you don't disable this feature then you are likely to run into trouble at the point when you log in to Ubuntu, as the Nvidia graphics drivers will probably load incorrectly.

Source: https://www.quantstart.com/articles/installing-tensorflow-on-ubuntu-1604-with-an-nvidia-gpu