# Nividia drivers, black screen after grub

Tags: 16.04, nvidia

Ubuntu 16.04, fresh install today.
I've tried switching to each of the nvidia drivers listed under "Additional Drivers", 367.57, 304.132, 340.98, and also tried the instructions [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/760934/graphics-issues-after-while-installing-ubuntu-16-04-16-10-with-nvidia-graphics) with adding the graphics-drivers/ppa and tried installing driver 370 which I believe is the latest.

..every time upon restart and getting past grub I get a black screen. Only fix is to reboot and use failsafeX to get back into the desktop to revert back to Nouveau. Are there any nvidia drivers which might work? Or other things to do?

Edit: So with 367.57 if I start Ubuntu with failsafeX the driver does work, it's just under normal boot I can't get as far as the login screen. Not sure exactly what failsafeX does differently to get to the login screen.

Comment: Disable Secure Boot in BIOS.

Comment: what is your driver's graphic card?

Comment: GTX560 is the card

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, looks like there is a problem rendering the splash screen stuff which is why I get a black screen. This is the fix I've found (turn all the shinies off).

On the Ubuntu grub entry, edit the `Linux` line, add `nomodeset` and **also** change `splash` and `quiet` to `nosplash` and `noquiet`.

Instructions [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/760374/ubuntu-16-04-nvidia-driver-blank-screen) on how to make that permanent. You might find it works with just `nomodeset` as that link suggests. I'm not sure why I need to change the additional configs too.