# Ubuntu 16.04 + Nvidia Driver + Encrypted harddrive = Blank screen

Tags: 16.04, drivers, nvidia, encryption

Steps:

- sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
- Install the nvidia via the "Additional Drivers"
- Reboot

After rebooting, getting a blank screen.

[Ubuntu 16.04 + Nvidia Driver = Blank screen](https://askubuntu.com/questions/760374/ubuntu-16-04-nvidia-driver-blank-screen) shows a lot of answers, but none fixed the issue.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found out that the issue is that the graphical "splash" screen that asks for the passphrase that is causing the issue with Nvidia drivers.

The fix is to remove the graphical splash and switch to pure text mode. Like that, I get a text passphrase prompt and then it goes on to boot the GUI without issue.

Steps to do after:

- Edit `/etc/default/grub`
- Remove `quiet splash` and replace with `text` in the line `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT`
- Save and execute `sudo update-grub`
- Reboot and enjoy