# Problems with Nouveau driver, NVIDIA drivers, and Videos official movie player

Tags: nvidia, nouveau

When I use the Nouveau display driver with a NVIDIA Quadro P4000, my system crashes when I try to view an animation with the Videos official movie player. (The animations can be viewed with VLC media player.) If I use one of NVIDIA's proprietary drivers (nvidia-driver-435, nvidia-driver-390, or nvidia-driver-430), the Videos movie player works but the option to decrypt my hard drives on startup is not displayed.  I can, however, input the password blindly to decrypt my hard drives and get the login prompt. I am enabling the NVIDIA drivers using the Additional Drivers tab in Software & Updates in Ubuntu 18.04.4.  I would like to get fixes for both types of drivers. BIOS 2.0b is current for Rev. 2.00 motherboard with 32MB SPI flash ROM.

Comment: I reinstalled Ubuntu 18.04.4 with the default Nouveau display driver.   If I open either the Gufw firewall or the Videos movie player, my login session crashes. I then installed the nvidia-driver-435 driver using the Additional Drivers tab in Software & Updates.  With the nvidia-driver-435, I can open Gufw and Videos.  Something is wrong with the most recent version of the default Nouveau display driver that causes logins to crash when opening certain packages.

Comment: When using nvidia-driver-435, the prompt to decrypt hard drives does not display. The solution is to boot into text mode as described here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/867643/ubuntu-16-04-nvidia-driver-encrypted-harddrive-blank-screen/867647.    This solution is not ideal because several screens of text will be displayed before and after your password is entered for decryption.

Comment: Show me the output of `sudo dmidecode -s bios-version` and tell me the make/model # of your computer.

Comment: The output is 2.0b.   It is a Supermicro Superserver 4023S-TRT.

Comment: BIOS 2.0b is current for Rev. 2.00 motherboard with 32MB SPI flash ROM. Please edit your question and show me `free -h` and `sysctl vm.swappiness` and `sudo lshw -C memory`. Have you ever run a memory test on this computer? Start comments to me with @heynnema or I may miss them.

Comment: @heynnema.  There is 512GB of memory and 26GB is used.  The swap size is 975MB. vm.swappiness=60.  The output for sudo 1shw -C memory is extensive.  How do you want me to display it?   I have not recently done a memory test.

Comment: Paste the `lshw` at paste.ubuntu.com and give me the URL.

Comment: @heynnema.   The output for lshw is here: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/2FX8j55GZr/.

Comment: The `lshw` looks fine. Thanks. Please see the update in my answer. With all of the problems that you have, it's probably time to test memory, especially if its never been done. Report back.

Comment: Status please...