# Ubuntu 16.04 - How to disable Nvidia driver from GRUB?

Tags: boot, drivers, grub2, nvidia, graphics

I am having an interesting issue.  I upgraded my graphics cards and now the NVidia driver does not recognize it.  As a result, when I attempt to boot into Ubuntu, I get spammed with an error stating that the driver has not recognized my card and then I get a black screen.

I have tried the follow:

1. set nvidia.modeset=0 in GRUB options
2. use nomodeset (following instructions here: [Ubuntu 16.04 + Nvidia Driver = Blank screen](https://askubuntu.com/questions/760374/ubuntu-16-04-nvidia-driver-blank-screen))
3. Boot into recovery mode and try "failsafe" graphics.  This led to my BIOS screaming a loud beeping at me.
4. Use the root command prompt from recovery mode.  This doesn't work since when I mount the drive (so I have write access so I can modify files) it loads the driver and I get spammed with the error.

Any ideas?  At this point I am about to call it quits and just re-install 16.04 from scratch.

Comment: What's with the downvotes? Troubleshooting issues w/ nvidia and grub are lamentably common.

Answer (score 8):

I got it to work!

Here's what I did:

1. Booted into recovery mode with root cmd prompt.
2. Mounted the drive with "mount --options remount,rw /"
3. Purged the drivers with "sudo apt-get purge nvidia-*"
4. At this point I was able to boot into Ubuntu, went to "Additional Drivers" and selected the latest available Nvidia driver.
5. Even after install, the driver wasn't see my card.  I had to go to tty1 (CTRL+ALT+F1) and run "sudo service lightdm restart".  My screen flickered a few times and then came back up in my monitor's native resolution.

Hope this helps others who are stuck.

Comment: Bravo! It works for me.