# Nvidia-304 driver goes black after login

Tags: 16.04, drivers, nvidia, graphics, nvidia-geforce

Upside: I'm learning a LOT about Linux and Ubuntu 16.04!

This is an HP laptop with Nvidia GeForce 7150M / nForce 650M gpu. It was running fine on the default Nouveau driver, but I used the Dash / Additional Drivers to select the legacy driver suggested. After successful login, the screen goes black except for mouse pointer.

When switching to terminal, usually the screen "whites out" slowly, but after switching between terminal and GUI a few times I can get a low-res terminal screen (with fuzzy glitches).

I tried nvidia-304 and nvidia-304-updates. I tried purging and reinstalling Nouveau. I managed to knock out some other functionality and have restored it, so now I'm back at the beginning (as described above).

Main question: what am  doing wrong?

Subquestions:
 - Should I be using `sudo apt-get remove` before trying a new driver set? 
 - How do I look at log files to find possible issues, and which log files?
 - If all else fails, how do I revert to Nouveau without losing other stuff (I had to `sudo apt-get upgrade` my 4.8.0-53 linux headers and image packages because mouse stopped working!)?

Thank you.

Comment: May I ask why you want to use the legacy driver instead of the latest one?

Comment: Legacy in the sense that it's a legacy gpu. I chose the latest one in the Updates & Drivers window, similar to the screenshot [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/760374/ubuntu-16-04-nvidia-driver-blank-screen#). 304 is in fact the latest driver for my gpu.

Comment: That's not true, according to Nvidia's website at least

Comment: Where do you see this? I looked up on their main drivers page, and also at http://www.nvidia.com/object/unix.html. Both say 304.135.

Comment: I just installed Lubuntu according to [this comment](https://askubuntu.com/a/788246/665279) and now the Ubuntu desktop appears, but is not usable. Clicking on desktop icons eventually causes them to be selected. Oddly, every letter 'i' in the icon descriptions is missing! (eg " nstall gpu dr ver")

Comment: Sorry for all the comments but Lubuntu is sortof working, very slowly. I got into Software Center, screen went black again. Alternating ALT+CTRL+F3 and ALT+CTRL+F7 got back to a usable command line, where I used `sudo service lightdm restart`. The gui came back and works for a while, but after a few clicks things disappear and go black again. Memory allocation issue maybe?