# Problem installing Nvidia driver on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: drivers, 20.04, nvidia

## The problem

Hi, I am having trouble installing the Nvidia drivers on my machine. The goal was to perform these simple commands:

```
$ ubuntu-drivers devices
```

And so, get something like:

```
modalias : pci:v000010DEd00001C8Csv00001028sd00000798bc03sc00i00
vendor   : NVIDIA Corporation
model    : GP107M [GeForce GTX 1050 Ti Mobile]
driver   : nvidia-driver-460 - distro non-free
driver   : nvidia-driver-418-server - distro non-free
driver   : nvidia-driver-470 - distro non-free recommended
driver   : nvidia-driver-450-server - distro non-free
driver   : nvidia-driver-460-server - distro non-free
driver   : nvidia-driver-390 - distro non-free
driver   : xserver-xorg-video-nouveau - distro free builtin
```

And after checking that everything was OK, just run this:

```
$ sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall
```

But I get this as a response inside the output of `ubuntu-drivers devices` and I can't do the next step `sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall`:

```
WARNING:root:_pkg_get_support nvidia-driver-390: package has invalid Support Legacyheader, cannot determine support level
```

**Important note** The drivers were working perfectly until today. But after the laptop ran out of battery (and it shut down because of this) the drivers, for some reason, vanished. The driver I had working and also the one I am going to try to install is the 470 from Nvidia, that is, I never installed the 390.

## Attempts of solutions I already tried

I have tried several (attempted) solutions, but they don't work, such as a simple

```
$ sudo apt update
$ sudo apt upgrade
$ sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall
```

but it does not work, then I tried

```
$ sudo apt-get remove --purge nvidia*
$ sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall
```

and it doesn't work either, I also tried with the quotes

```
$ sudo apt-get remove --purge "nvidia*"
$ sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall
```

but it keeps failing

## My configs

### Ubuntu version

```
$ cat /etc/os-release

NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="20.04.3 LTS (Focal Fossa)"
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS"
VERSION_ID="20.04"
HOME_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://help.ubuntu.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/"
PRIVACY_POLICY_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/legal/terms-and-policies/privacy-policy"
VERSION_CODENAME=focal
UBUNTU_CODENAME=focal
```

### Kernel version

```
$ uname -a 

Linux DellInspiron 5.11.0-34-generic #36~20.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Fri Aug 27 08:06:32 UTC 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

### Drivers list

```
$ ubuntu-drivers list

WARNING:root:_pkg_get_support nvidia-driver-390: package has invalid Support Legacyheader, cannot determine support level
nvidia-driver-450-server, (kernel modules provided by linux-modules-nvidia-450-server-generic-hwe-20.04)
nvidia-driver-460-server, (kernel modules provided by linux-modules-nvidia-460-server-generic-hwe-20.04)
nvidia-driver-390, (kernel modules provided by linux-modules-nvidia-390-generic-hwe-20.04)
nvidia-driver-418-server, (kernel modules provided by linux-modules-nvidia-418-server-generic-hwe-20.04)
nvidia-driver-470, (kernel modules provided by linux-modules-nvidia-470-generic-hwe-20.04)
nvidia-driver-460, (kernel modules provided by linux-modules-nvidia-460-generic-hwe-20.04)
```

### Devices list

```
$ ubuntu-drivers devices

WARNING:root:_pkg_get_support nvidia-driver-390: package has invalid Support Legacyheader, cannot determine support level
== /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.0/0000:01:00.0 ==
modalias : pci:v000010DEd00001C8Csv00001028sd00000798bc03sc00i00
vendor   : NVIDIA Corporation
model    : GP107M [GeForce GTX 1050 Ti Mobile]
driver   : nvidia-driver-460 - distro non-free
driver   : nvidia-driver-418-server - distro non-free
driver   : nvidia-driver-470 - distro non-free recommended
driver   : nvidia-driver-450-server - distro non-free
driver   : nvidia-driver-460-server - distro non-free
driver   : nvidia-driver-390 - distro non-free
driver   : xserver-xorg-video-nouveau - distro free builtin
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Nvidia drivers Ubuntu 18.04 - Dell G5 15](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1159795/nvidia-drivers-ubuntu-18-04-dell-g5-15)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

After researching in several forums, I found a partial solution [here](https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/nvidia-smi-has-failed-because-it-couldnt-communicate-with-the-nvidia-driver-make-sure-that-the-latest-nvidia-driver-is-installed-and-running/111008/99) by the user alok.fj

The steps are quite simple, I put all the steps here in order:

```
$ sudo apt update
$ sudo apt upgrade
$ sudo apt autoremove
$ sudo apt-get remove --purge nvidia*
$ sudo apt-get remove --purge "nvidia*"
```

Then I run (as the original idea was)

```
$ ubuntu-drivers devices

WARNING:root:_pkg_get_support nvidia-driver-390: package has invalid Support Legacyheader, cannot determine support level
modalias : pci:v000010DEd00001C8Csv00001028sd00000798bc03sc00i00
vendor   : NVIDIA Corporation
model    : GP107M [GeForce GTX 1050 Ti Mobile]
driver   : nvidia-driver-460 - distro non-free
driver   : nvidia-driver-418-server - distro non-free
driver   : nvidia-driver-470 - distro non-free recommended
driver   : nvidia-driver-450-server - distro non-free
driver   : nvidia-driver-460-server - distro non-free
driver   : nvidia-driver-390 - distro non-free
driver   : xserver-xorg-video-nouveau - distro free builtin
```

Note that I still get the WARNING, but instead of running <s>`sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall`</s>, run the command explicitly clarifying the desired driver version:

```
sudo apt install nvidia-driver-470
sudo reboot
```

Once you have rebooted, test the installation with `nvidia-smi` and you should get something like this:

```
$ nvidia-smi

+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 470.57.02    Driver Version: 470.57.02    CUDA Version: 11.4     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|                               |                      |               MIG M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  NVIDIA GeForce ...  Off  | 00000000:01:00.0  On |                  N/A |
| N/A   50C    P0    N/A /  N/A |    447MiB /  4040MiB |      1%      Default |
|                               |                      |                  N/A |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
...
```

### TL; DR

```
$ sudo apt update
$ sudo apt upgrade
$ sudo apt autoremove
$ sudo apt-get remove --purge nvidia*
$ sudo apt-get remove --purge "nvidia*"
$ sudo apt install nvidia-driver-470      (you may need other version)
$ sudo reboot
```

Test with

```
$ nvidia-smi
```

Comment: This fixed me right up. After rebooting, I had an "unclaimed" video output. Removing and reinstalling drivers fixed it. Thank you.

Comment: I'm using KDE and it freezes on boot on a black screen

Comment: Really great, the settings are now remembered which previously (even when I was able to rotate the display) they weren't. Still haven't yet persuaded the logon screen to be rotated but that's a minor issue by comparison. Thanks.

Comment: This solution works for me (just no need `reboot`).

Answer (score 1):

I tried all these steps but the underlying issue was the Secure Boot was Enabled. Disabling **Secure Boot** did the job.