# NVidia drivers installing error

Tags: drivers, nvidia

```
WARNING:root:_pkg_get_support nvidia-driver-510: package has invalid Support PBheader, cannot determine support level
WARNING:root:_pkg_get_support nvidia-driver-390: package has invalid Support Legacyheader, cannot determine support level
WARNING:root:_pkg_get_support nvidia-driver-510-server: package has invalid Support PBheader, cannot determine support level
```

Comment: Open a terminal and type `apt list nvidia-driver-*` then edit your question above, posting the result please.

Comment: You might want to see:  https://askubuntu.com/questions/1362970/problem-installing-nvidia-driver-on-ubuntu-20-04