# Laptop freezes before login: Nvidia driver 430 - Ubuntu 18.04 - 4.18.0-25-generic

Tags: 18.04, nvidia

I looked around in a lot of different posts and websites but the result is always the same: once I reboot I never reach again the login scree - the laptop freezes with a black screen.

I tried a lot a different actions but none helped me to find a solution for my current configuration:
Ubuntu: 18.04
Kernel: 4.18.0-25-generic
Graphic card: Quadro P3200

I currently run the 390.116 nvidia driver version as an alternative to the nouveau ubuntu nvidia drivers.
This version is the ONLY one I can run on my system.

I tried PPA packages (410, 415, 418 and 430) but none of them work.

I also tried the 430 version recently "officially" proposed by Ubuntu but with no luck.

In the BIOS I have:
- Disable the secure boot
- Forced the dGPU to replace the iGPU (no card switching)
In addition I have:
- in /lib/modprobe.d/nvidia-kms.conf added the following line: options nvidia-drm modeset=0
- Always prime-select set to nvidia

To test the other versions I also tried:
- To blacklist nouveau
- To add nomodeset in GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT
but both of these actions were not required for having the 390 version working.

Can someone tell me where the problem is?

Thanks!!!

Comment: Did you check this [post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/744419/blank-screen-after-nvidia-install)?

Comment: The post you mention is not related to the nvidia driver I am trying to install. The driver is even older than what I already have. In addition, if you read carefully my post, I blacklisted nouveau driver, which is what they do by modifying the grub default.. Unfortunately that is not the answer.

Comment: I know it is not the same driver version, what I wanted mention in that post is adding `nouveau.modeset=0` to the config file. And since you already tried it, the post is not useful for you anymore.