# video drivers not working ubuntu. 800x600 only resolution

Tags: drivers, graphics, display, intel, display-resolution

Just installed ubuntu 14.04 on Asus GL552.
Forced resolution to 800x600.

Graphics Card - Nvidia 960GTX (not working, thus uninstalled)
Intel HD 530.  (not in use)

Kindly help me out, atleast intel drivers should be working and I can get normal resolution.  Nvidia thing - later on.

```
lspci -k | grep -EA2 'VGA|3d'
VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporatation Device 191b (rev 06)
Subsystem: ASUSTek Computer Inc. Device 1c5d
3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GM107M[Geforce GTX 960M] (rev a2)
Subsystem: ASUSTek Computer Inc. Device 1c5d
```

Answer (score 0):

I am referring to this answer from my other answers. I had a login loop issue as mentioned [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/721633/nvidia-graphics-card-driver-installed-led-to-login-loop). It seems you are also encountering a different issue due to nvidia drivers and this could fix your issue.

First uninstall the currently installed NVIDIA drivers.Boot the computer, when the GRUB menu appears ...

Highlight the Ubuntu menu entry and press the E key.Add `nouveau.modeset=0` to the end of the linux line. Press F10 to boot the Ubuntu operating system.

When the login screen appears press Ctrl + Alt + F1 .Enter your user name and the password, then execute :

```
sudo apt-get purge nvidia*  
sudo reboot
```

Now install the latest official stable NVIDIA drivers.Boot the computer, when the GRUB menu appears ...

Highlight the Ubuntu menu entry and press the E key.Add `nouveau.modeset=0` to the end of the linux line. Press F10 to boot the Ubuntu operating system.

When the login screen appears press Ctrl + Alt + F1. Enter your user name and the password, then execute :

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nvidia-361
sudo reboot
```

Note : Maybe it is explicitly necessary to select the NVIDIA adapter in BIOS.

In case you have installed the nvidia driver from their site then uninstall it as per that instructions.Uninstall that driver by running, as root, `sh ./NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-361.28.run` and follow the on screen instructions.

***Note : The solution I have provide has been tested on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS and Ubuntu 15.10 for two Nvidia GPUs***

Comment: Umm, yup I tried those.  Didn't work.  Same problem.  Stuck at login loop.
Thats the reason I uninstalled the nvidia drivers again.

Even I installed the suggested drivers from Ubuntu Software *addtional drivers* tab.

and also from , 
sudo ubuntu-drivers devices

Comment: Login loop issue is not just for graphics driver issue but for some other reasons also. In case you are not able to login...try Ctrl+Alt+F1(F1 to F6) to login to tty and then go thru the logs under /var/log directory. You can get some hints from there.

Comment: yeah, exactly thats how I uninstalled the nvidia drivers and got UI again.

Answer (score 0):

Press **ctrl**+**alt**+**F2** at the login screen.

log in from the shell and type:

**sudo apt-get install xubuntu-desktop**

**sudo reboot**

After reboot click up at the right corner that has the ubuntu icon and choose xubuntu and log in.

Now go to additional drivers and choose the proprietary drivers marked as **tested**

Reboot.

Choose the ubuntu icon up on the right corner and log in.