# How to install ubuntu 14.04.4 on Asus n552vx i7 6700HQ?

Tags: 14.04, dual-boot, system-installation

I have a problem with my new laptop. On this pc i have preinstalled win 10. I disabled fast boot and secure boot. When i click to try or install Ubuntu it freezes while loading. 
How can i solve this?

Asus n552vx 
I7 6700HQ 
8Gb Ram
Gtx 950
Full-Hd monitor 1920x1080

Comment: Please refer to my [response](http://askubuntu.com/questions/744698/video-drivers-not-working-ubuntu-800x600-only-resolution/744701#744701). You have to use the same set of steps for your nvidia graphics card to get it fixed.

Comment: Did you try to install Ubuntu 16.04? Did you get same behaviour?