# Login loop out of the blue with NVIDIA GPU

Tags: 16.04, drivers, login, nvidia-geforce

First of all, I checked [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/858473/ubuntu-14-04-login-loop-with-nvidia-proprietary-driver), [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/760934/graphics-issues-after-while-installing-ubuntu-16-04-16-10-with-nvidia-graphics), [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/693454/infinite-login-loop-with-nvidia-proprietary-graphics), and [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/866854/login-loop-with-nvidia-drivers-another-one) threads and neither the solutions nor the problems themselves correspond exactly to my issue.

The **setup** in which my issue occurs:

GPU: NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1050.
Ubuntu: 16.04 LTS.

**The issue:**

After installing NVIDIA's drivers (NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-375.20) everything works just fine. However, out of the blue, *every 7~10 days*, I will get a login loop that forces me to purge drivers, stop lightdm, re-install, and reboot. This works every single time, so the issue has a solution but it keeps happening every other week.

**Measures taken:**

So far the only measure I have adopted is including nomodeset to my Grub. I thought this would fix the issue but since I included it the problem occurred twice (so that means I included nomodeset like a month ago).

The fact that the issue happens periodically makes me think that it is related to some process that also occurs every other week. I might be wrong, but I just wanted to check with the community as I am a Linux aficionado and not an expert in any way.

Any lead/idea/suggestion will be very appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry to say this, but I think you should escalate this to your Gfx card's warranty division. It is always surprising what a single semi failed transistor can do.

Comment: Anyways, the good news is that everything is probably ok, and a little work will get it fixed up.

As a first debugging step, even thought it seems paradoxical, could you try uninstalling the nvidia drivers with something like

$ sudo apt-get remove nvidia-*

Comment: Thanks for your reply. As stated in OP, purging Nvidia drivers is part of the fix I work with. Hopefully it isn't a hardware problem. I'll keep looking for a permanent solution, although, who knows, maybe the issue won't happen again...