# no NVIDIA driver currently installed but they appear in Additional Drivers

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, xorg, cuda

I tried to install cuda-8 (successfully), then tried to install NVIDIA drivers. I have a GT 755m which requires 375 drivers, so I downloaded the [375.39 version from nvidia.com](http://www.nvidia.com/download/driverResults.aspx/114708/en-us) and when I finished it I ended up in the [login loop problem](https://askubuntu.com/questions/721633/nvidia-graphics-card-driver-installed-led-to-login-loop).

I solved it and now I can use Ubuntu again, however the Additional Drivers reports this list of NVIDIA drivers:

[image]

Probably I tried to install them in the past and I think they're going to pollute the system. How can I remove them? I tried to download the propriety and run `sudo ./NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-375.26.run --uninstall` but then this message is returned:

[image]

Same for 367 and 340. How can I remove them?

Comment: Do you really need CUDA? If you don't need CUDA do not install it. CUDA at the moment works only with Nvidia drivers and if you aren't using them and are happy it suggests you don't need CUDA.

Comment: Installing Nvidia drivers in Ubuntu should be done preferably trough Additional drivers. The versions available in the repositories and to a lesser extend the ones from the semi-official PPA have been tested to work in Ubuntu.

Comment: I work with CUDA, Sorry :D

Comment: At the moment no, you don't.

Comment: @CelticWarrior what do you mean? That it is not necessary for installing nvidia drivers? If that's what you mean you're right, but the next step is installing CUDA since I'm installing these driver to run it :D

Comment: It seems you're having some trouble understanding plain English. I said the exact opposite: **CUDA requires Nvidia proprietary drivers**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing to remove. Nvidia proprietary drivers are not installed.

You see them because they are available for installation.

Comment: Can CUDA work with `nouveau`?

Comment: @CelticWarrior I have no idea. I never used CUDA.

Comment: There's WIP apparently but no news since mid-205: https://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=NVIDIA-Nouveau-CUDA-Support